# Best way of create/delete/restyle graph dynamically with Plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I want to add and delete graphs with buttons on my page. 
   I have to pass layout, and data as Json to the plotly.plot() function.
   How can i do this dynamically?

Example code from reference :

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  width: 500,
  height: 500
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data,layout);
```

i receive my data via ajax from a database.

```
function getTrace_data(x,y) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get.php?action=data&x="+x+"&y="+y
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      drawGraph(data);
    },
    error: function(error){ 
      console.log(error);
    }  
  });
}

function drawGraph(data)
{
  var trace1 = {
    x: data.x,
    y: data.y,
    type: 'scatter'
  };

  var layout = {
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  };
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data,layout);
}
```

Now i can draw a graph, but how should i change the type of the graph dynamically? or layout options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just overwrite the existing graph with a new one and dynamically change the layout of your graph with a few variables, see the snippet below. Just assume the buttons are different AJAX calls.

```js
function changeGraph(graphType) {
    var traces = [];
    var graph_types = [];
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    switch (graphType) {
    case 1:
        graph_types.push("scatter");
        graph_types.push("bar");
        break;
    case 2:
        graph_types.push("bar");
        graph_types.push("bar");
        break;
    default:
        graph_types.push("scatter");
        graph_types.push("scatter");
    }
    traces.push({
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
        type: graph_types[0]
    });

    traces.push({
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
        type: graph_types[1]
    });

    var layout = {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    };

    Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, traces, layout);
}

document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener("click", function () {
    changeGraph(0);
});
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () {
    changeGraph(1);
});
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function () {
    changeGraph(2);
});

document.getElementById("button0").click();
```

```html
<script src=https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<button id="button0">Scatter only</button>
<button id="button1">Bar&Scatter</button>
<button id="button2">Bars only</button>
```